# Im having trouble with a university question, the final calculation doesnt end up in the same numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Question - Create a function dinner_calculator(meal_cost, drinks_cost) that calculates and returns the total cost of the meal for a small restaurant during happy hour (drinks only are discounted).

The function takes two values, the cost of the meals and drinks before GST.
Before GST is applied, a 30% discount needs to be applied to the drinks cost.
Goods and services tax (GST) needs to be added to the meal and drinks cost, GST is set to 15%.
The function should return the total cost.
In our tests, we round the answer you return to 2 decimal places before printing but don't worry about that - your function should simply return the exact answer (to the extent that any floating point calculation is "exact").

---

```
def dinner_calculator(meal_cost, drinks_cost):
""" Calculate the cost of dinner during happy hour.
    Takes into consideration:
     - Pre-GST meal and drink costs
     - Happy Hour discounts
     - GST
"""
meal_cost = meal_cost + meal_cost * 0.15
drinks_cost = drinks_cost * 0.70 + drinks_cost * 0.15
total_cost = meal_cost + drinks_cost
return round(total_cost,2)
```

[The image below is what the code should return and what is being returned by mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLZll.png)

---

any help will be greatly greatly appreciated, thanks so much in advance guys !!!!

Comment: `drinks_cost = drinks_cost * 0.70 + drinks_cost * 0.15`.  You're adding the 15% tax on the full drinks cost before the 30% discount.

Comment: this is a math problem rather than programming.....

Comment: Are the computed meal costs or the drink costs wrong? Point is, you need to reduce your problem. The general rule is that questions should come with a [mcve] (copy'n'paste your code into a file and run it, at least) and both the expected and actual output. Provide the output as text, unless there's a good reason not to. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply the GST before applying the discount on drinks cost, You should change your code a little bit:

```
def dinner_calculator(meal_cost, drinks_cost):

    drinks_cost = drinks_cost * 0.70
    meal_cost = meal_cost + meal_cost * 0.15
    drinks_cost = drinks_cost + drinks_cost * 0.15
    total_cost = meal_cost + drinks_cost
    return round(total_cost,2)
```